# is there a size limit for inline strings in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

Is there a string size limitation for any of the cases below?

```
str1 = 'looong text'
str2 = "#{text_var}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No size limitation.

You can define long multi-line strings either through "HERE" documents like this:

```
str = <<THE_END    

some

very 

long 

text

THE_END
```

or like this:

```
str = %Q{
some

very

long

text

}
```